# Read File from Web with HttpClient

Tags: android, android-webview, android-file

I am trying to read a file from the web with httpclient and am getting this error.  What am I doing wrong?  Code sample would be appreciated.

```
11-02 17:21:09.845: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-02 17:21:10.464: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{405591c0 com.jeffbreunig/.RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity}
11-02 17:21:15.534: DEBUG/dalvikvm(310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 64ms
11-02 17:21:18.244: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-02 17:21:20.998: DEBUG/(1879): DID NOT WORK
11-02 17:21:21.344: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed com.jeffbreunig/.RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity: +21s38ms
```

code:

```
public class RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity extends Activity  {

    private static final String TAG = null;
    TextView txt;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        String urlToRead = "http://webdev4.matcmadison.edu/mbtest/mab/AmazonXML/FileList.txt";
        try {
        String fileList = getContent(urlToRead);

        txt.setText(fileList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "DUMP FILES DID NOT WORK");
        }



    }



    public String getContent(String url) {

        String responseBody;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
            responseBody = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG,"DID NOT WORK");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + ex.getMessage(), 6000).show();
            return "Failure to read from server!";
        }

        return responseBody;

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        String s = String.format("You chose [%s]", items[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>parent) {

    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jeffbreunig"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name=".RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity"
                      android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a some kind of threading mechanism for fetching the data over http. I suggest an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well propably the problem is you are doing this on Android 3.0 and above, right?
There, you are forced to use AsyncClass for consumig web services or downloading something from internet as your main UI thread can not be unresponsive (there is a limit for how long can the UI thread be "locked" by long running code ) ;-)

Comment: Yes, was Android 3.0, also tried Android 2.1 with same result